# HP DL380 Gen 9 + P440ar + SSD

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, raid5, hpe

I am looking at installing 4 HPE 480GB SATA 6G SFF SSD in a DL380 Gen 9, running a P440ar smart array controller. The plan is to run a RAID 5 volume, then install Windows Server 2016.

1. Is RAID 5 the best solution for a 4 drive setup (additional drives are not budgeted for)?
2. Will the RAID 5 setup have any significant performance impact on the OS, and user experience? The server will be used in an engineering office, and be used for running electrical systems modelling software (generally not a massive burden).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RAID 5 will be fine with those SSDs. Otherwise, RAID 1+0 is okay too, assuming the capacity is sufficient.

For your use case, you won't notice any major differences between the two RAID levels.

Comment: Thanks for that. As an aside, would I see big gains moving to 12G SAS SSD? Are they worth the additional investment for the described work load?

Comment: No. Probably not worth it.